# Tilt sensor to work with Google Earth

Tags: c#, microcontroller, google-earth

I'm working with a microcontroller and trying to use the tilt sensor to control the panning and rotating of the google earth image. I already have the tilt sensor connected to the C# code and can get data from it. What are the relavant functions that I would use to do navigate google earth in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this open source library of control I have put together that intergrates the Google Earth Plugin into managed code.

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

The standard Api objects for navigation are the KmlLookAt and KmlCamera:
http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_look_at.html
http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_camera.html

(FYI, I have been doing something similar using the Wiring IO board!)